# How to use id_token instead of access_token in Oauth2 in Postman?

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, amazon-cognito

I've recently started using Postman and I've started testing an endpoint that has been secured using AWS Cognito. I've setup the OAuth 2.0 Authorization section in Postman correctly and I'm getting a response with 3 types of tokens: id_token, access_token and refresh_token. By default, Postman is putting the access_token in the Authorization header and I need to use the id_token. Is there any way I can extract the id_token from the response and use it in my requests? I think there should be a way to pass it onto a global/environment variable so I can define the header myself using that.

Comment: id_token is not part of oauth2. there is no identity management in oauth, just authorization one.

Comment: I understand. One of my issues is that Postman uses one type of token by default after successful authorization. There's only a "Use Token" option which takes the access_token.

Comment: This is the problem I'm facing as well. I need to get the JWT which is coming as an id_token and use that for authorization with APIs

Answer (score 0):

You can create two request first to get `id_token` and set environment variable and then to check your endpoint using that variable in headers.

You can extract id_token using `tests` (AKA post-request script) and create and set an environment variable. Then use it in next request in header as {{your_variable name}}.

See https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples/ for more details.

Comment: I managed to create a separate GET and POST request. I can pass the authorization code and then get a proper json response where I can choose which token to use but the new issue is that I still have to login manually to AWS Cognito via the Authorization panel in Postman.

Comment: @escape_artist Which auth are you using in second request?

Comment: I'm using <myhost>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token

Comment: @escape_artist According to your original question you needed id_token which you are getting. And you have to add access_token in each request according to Amazon Cognito docs. So what is problem that you are facing from postman currently?